# ag-grid Angular: Passing parameters to component when using Cell Render?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a table where one of the columns displays a link, that click on it opens a new page. 
To display the specific link I'm using:

```
 `cellRenderer: "motorBikeType"`, under `this.columnDefs = [...`
```

In order to display the different motorbikes types in the column, I'm using the **`agInit`** function (as I was answered here before) from the `motorBikeType` **`component`** , to get access to the column data through `params.data.motorBikeType`

This works fine. The table displays correctly and I get a nice link for each type of motorcycle.

The problem starts when I click the link. In the new page that opens (which pretty much is the `motorBikeType` component, the `params.node.data.motorBikeType` is no longer available.

If I console.log it - I'll see it in the console. But it will not let me bind to the html view of `motorBikeType`

I even tried to create a local variable in the class, something like:

```
export class motorBikeType {
   ...
   motorbike: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.motorbike = params.data.motorBikeType;
}

}
```

and then in the html view:

```
<a *ngIf="... >{{params.data.motorBikeType}}</a>

<p *ngIf="...>{{params.data.motorBikeType}}</a>
```

It will only display in the table column the link , but once it redirect to the page (I'm using the router), it will not show the paragraph with the binding value.

I tried also inside `ngOnInit() {...` to do `this.motorbike = this.params.data.motorBikeType;`

But it still not binding in the view.

Pretty much what I need is to display `params.data.motorBikeType` in the view.

something like `<p>{{params.data.motorBikeType}}` or `<p>{{motorbike}}</p>`

Thanks.

Comment: your cell renderer motorBikeType is only a way to route to different views, it should not ideally hold the view logic